# Sending json with enter key to php web service

Tags: php, json

I am working on PHP web service for android app.

Here I am sending json :

```
{"company":"wipro","user_id":19,"title":"title_update","from_date":"01-02-2014","to_date":"11-02-2014","additional_notes":"worked with 3 reputed firms"}
```

this is a valid json but requirement is that user can press **'Enter key'** in *additional_notes parameter* which invalidates the json. Is there any solution possible for such problem?
If this is impossible to send json with enter key then is that possible with ***Xml*** .

Comment: Strip newline characters?

Comment: @marty let me try that! But I think the time i press enter Rest client stops decoding that json as it becomes invalid.

Comment: @marty it didn't worked. As earlier it is giving same error : Message: Decoding failed: Syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I understood your problem, you want to send the additional_notes key with value containing new-line character ('\n').

For example

```
{"company":"wipro","user_id":19,"title":"title_update","from_date":"01-02-2014","to_date":"11-02-2014","additional_notes":"worked with 3 reputed firms \n currently working with abc"}
```

the line `currently working with abc` was the text on the new-line.

If you are using text-area for additional_notes then it will automatically add '\n' character for new line. Adding new-line character ('\n') will not invalidate the json. What invalidates the json is when you break the value of additional_notes key to the next line in your script code.

Comment: VVK brilliant ! let me try this solution.

Comment: VVk I have a doubt. What will have when they embed this service with their android code because then users will press enter and in json enter will not be entertained!

Comment: @Simer I'm not getting what you are saying. If you use a text-area for additional_notes then it will automatically add new line char in the json. This behavior is also followed in android os.

Comment: VVK in android \n is replaced with line break so in request i again get **'line-break'** which invalidates json.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an list/array of single text lines. Parse your multi line text before sending into single line strings and on your  server you need to put them together again. 
Your json should then look something like this:

```
{"multi_line_text":["line one","line two","line three"]}
```

It is not the best solution but it should work